# Differentiate regular commit pushes from an out-of-date update in a Pull Request using GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions, pull-request

A `pull_request` GitHub action runs when the `synchronize` event is triggered. This happens when a commit is pushed to the pull request.

If a user updates the branch with master, by pressing the following button:
[image]
these actions also get triggered.

I have an action that should only work when a user pushes a new commit, and this **should not run** when they update their branch with master.

Is there any way to differentiate this kind of push from a regular push in a pull request?

Comment: Pressing that button _does_ add a new commit to the head branch, why shouldn't the workflow run?

Comment: It's a very niche requirements, but we need to dismiss external reviewers when a new commit is added, and using the push events dismiss their reviews even when the branch is updated, which it should be the exception.